# Javascript: how to visit the 'this' member of a construction function?

Tags: javascript

In console, I created a construction function 'Car' like below,
  and new-ed a object named 'mycar', and it happend like this:

```
> var Car = function() {
... this.make = "Ford";
... }
undefined

> var mycar = new Car()
undefined

> mycar.make   // when I visit mycar.make, it worked
'Ford'

> Car.make      // when I visit Car.make, it didn't work
undefined
```

So I want to ask:

how to visit the 'Car.make' like I visit the 'mycar.make'?

> clarify: to visit `make` via the name `Car` but not via `mycar`

where did the field `this.make="Ford"` go?

I also tried to expand its `__proto__` in Chrome dev console, but didn't found it.

Thanks!

Comment: `make` is defined on the new instance which is created using `new Car()`. So, you can access `make` using `mycar`(the instance). The `make` property is not defined on _prototype_, so you cannot see it in console.

Comment: `this` is window.. `where did the field this.make="Ford" go?`, check your `window.make`..

Comment: @choz not when using `Car` as a constructor.

Comment: @DanielA.White My bad.. Wasnt paying attention..

Comment: @Tushar  So basically, it's not possible to visit the `make` by the name `Car`, right?

Comment: that wouldn't make sense @panda_twx. `Car` is being used as a constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Before `this`

Let's take a close look at the following piece of code :

```
Car = function (brand) {
  this.brand = brand;
}

Car.prototype.getBrand = function () {
  return this.brand;
};

ford = new Car("Ford");
fiat = new Car("Fiat");
ford.getBrand(); // "Ford"
fiat.getBrand(); // "Fiat"
```

At first glance you may think that `getBrand` is owned by `ford` and `fiat`, but it's wrong. When you want to know how things are organized in memory you should not rely on the code alone, it can be misleading. Here is a proper snapshot :

```
/
├── Car
│   └── prototype
│       └── getBrand
├── ford
│   ├── brand
│   └── __proto__ -> /Car/prototype
└── fiat
    ├── brand
    └── __proto__ -> /Car/prototype
```

Think of it as a folder structure where directories are objects, files are attributes or methods, and links are references to other objects. As I said, `/ford/getBrand` doesn't exist. Check by yourself, `ford.hasOwnProperty("getBrand")` gives `false`. So, you may ask, why `ford.getBrand()` doesn't crashes ? This is where this weird stuff called `__proto__` comes in.

`__proto__` is a property that you can find in every object. In our code, `/ford/__proto__` could be seen as a link to `/Car/prototype`. It could also be seen as a hidden file since you won't see it if you write `console.log(ford)`. The fact is that you are not supposed to play with it, "The use of `__proto__` is controversial, and has been discouraged." (read more on this at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto)).

But beyond the `__proto__` controversy, `ford.getBrand()` works because JavaScript implements what's called a lookup mechanism. When it fails to find something into an object, it will keep searching into the prototype of this object. As it happens, since `/ford/getBrand` does not exist, JavaScript will look into `/ford/__proto__`.

What I want to show you is that there is a lot of things that happen behind the scene, but there is nothing magical. The language performs some tricks that you have to find and demistify :-)

### About `this`

`this` is a contextual keyword, in other words, its value depends on a context. A context (= a scope) is a set of values. For example, the global context (`/`) contains `Car`, `ford` and `fiat`, but it also contains `this`, which refers to... the global context itself ! More interesting, JavaScript allows you to create new contexts. As far as I know, calling a function is the only way to do it :

```
function f (v) {
  // context birth
  // ...
  // context death
}
f(); // new local context
f(); // new local context
```

In a local context like the one above, `this` refers to the global context by default. You may want to overwrite the default behaviour, unfortunately you can't write `this = anything`. Nevermind, you can still take control over `this` using the `new` keyword, a contextual call or... brute force !

By default :

```
Car("Ford");
console.log(brand);
// prints "Ford" :-\ told you,
// in the context of `Car`
// `this` refers to the global 
// context by default
```

With the `new` keyword :

```
audi = new Car("Audi");
// in the context of `Car`
// `this` refers to `audi`
```

With a contextual call :

```
ford.getBrand(); // "Ford"
// in the context of `getBrand`
// `this` refers to `ford`
```

Using "brute force" :

```
ford.getBrand.call(fiat); // "Fiat"
// in the context of `getBrand`
// `this` refers to `fiat` !
```

However, as you can see, `this` never refers to `Car`, that's why `/Car/brand` is missing. Adding properties to `this` from the inside of the constructor modifies the instance (`ford`, `fiat` or `audi`), not the class (`Car`).

### After `this`

Trace of `ford = new Car("Ford")` :

```
1. /Car exists ? yes
2. create a new object
3. call Car with this = the new object
  3.1. add __proto__ to this
  3.2. set this.__proto__ to /Car/prototype
  3.1. add brand to this
  3.2. set this.brand to "Ford"
  3.3. return this (the new object)
4. set ford to the new object
```

Trace of `ford.getBrand.call(fiat)` :

```
1. /ford exists ? yes
2. /ford/getBrand exists ? no
3. /ford/__proto__/getBrand exists ? yes
4. call /ford/__proto__/getBrand with this = fiat
  4.1. /fiat exists ? yes
  4.2. /fiat/brand exists ? yes
  4.3. return /fiat/brand
```

A short demo :

```js
Car = function (brand) {
  console.log("this === Car =", this === Car);
  this.brand = brand;
}

Car.prototype.getBrand = function () {
  console.log("this === ford =", this === ford);
  return this.brand;
};

ford = new Car("Ford");
ford.getBrand();

console.log("ford.hasOwnProperty(\"getBrand\") =", ford.hasOwnProperty("getBrand"));
console.log("Car.prototype === ford.__proto__ =", Car.prototype === ford.__proto__);
console.log("Car =", Car);
console.log("ford =", ford);
console.log("Car.prototype =", Car.prototype);
console.log("ford.__proto__ =", ford.__proto__);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `this` keyword in the function refers to the object being created by the `new` keyword.

If you want to create a "static" property, you would have to set it directly on the function name like this:

```
function Car() {
}

Car.make = "Ford";
```

Basically you can't have "both". The property is either static (on the function itself) or instance (on the object created by `new`)

Comment: *this* isn't "context". There are [*execution contexts*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/index.html#sec-10.3) that have *this* as one of their parameters. ;-)