# Javascript inheritance puzzles me

Tags: javascript, node.js, inheritance

I am trying to understand JavaScript inheritance and I hit a road block. I am not familiar with JavaScript's prototype based inheritance. I am still using old NodeJS version so I can't use classes.

Could you tell me why following code prints the same values for different workers and how can I prevent it?

```
var Manager = require('./manager');

var worker1 =  new Manager.getWorker('foo');
var worker2 =  new Manager.getWorker('bar');

console.log(worker1.config);
console.log(worker2.config);

//Implementation Details

//Manager
(function() {
    'use strict';

    function Manager() {

    }

    Manager.getWorker = function(slug) {
        var Worker = null;
        try {
            Worker = require('./workers/' + slug);
            Worker = new Worker();
        } catch (e) {
            console.log('Worker error: cannot initiate worker');
        }
        return Worker;
    };
    module.exports = Manager;
})();

//foo.js
(function () {
    var _abstract = require('../abstract_worker');
    var _util = require('util');


    var config = {
        "slug": "foo",
        "name": "Foo Worker"
    };

    function Foo() {
        this.config = config;
        Foo.super_.apply(this,arguments);
    }
    _util.inherits(Foo, _abstract);
    module.exports = Foo;
})();

//bar.js
'use strict';

(function () {
    var _abstract = require('../abstract_worker');
    var _util = require('util');


    var config = {
        "slug": "bar",
        "name": "Bar Worker"
    };

    function Bar() {
        this.config = config;
        Bar.super_.apply(this,arguments);
    }
    _util.inherits(Bar, _abstract);
    module.exports = Bar;
})();

(function() {
    'use strict';
    //config
    var _ = require('lodash');

    var default_config = {
        number_of_job: 1
    };

    function AbstractWorker() {
        if (!this.config) {
            this.config = {};
        }

        if (!_.isString(this.config.slug)) {
            throw new Error('config.slug is undefined.');
        }

        if (!_.isString(this.config.name)) {
            throw new Error('config.name is undefined.');
        }
        this.config = _.merge(default_config, this.config);
    }
    module.exports = AbstractWorker;

})();
```

**EDIT**: Thanks to @Bergi I found out the source of the error. It seems Lodash's `merge` recursively merges own and inherited enumerable string keyed properties of source objects into the destination object. In my code it seems I also made a typo and wrote in wrong order. I just leave it as it is maybe it can help others in the long run.

Comment: JS classes still use prototypal inheritance, by the way. They just hide it.

Comment: Is this really the smallest and simplest demonstration you could come up with?

Comment: I would recommend Kyle Simpson's [`YDKJS`](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/), specifically [this chapter](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/ch5.md)

Comment: @melpomene I am sorry. I tried to make it as small as possible. I am sorry again for the trouble.

Comment: Well, your example immediately fails in the first line for me: `var Manager = require('./manager');`

Comment: @melpomene You have to put them into separate files.. hence the comments like `//foo.js` and `//bar.js`

Comment: `manager.js` must be in the same folder which I gave in my code. There also must be folders named `workers` which has `foo.js` and `bar.js`

Comment: No, that's too complicated. A [mcve] should be pasteable into a simple file.

Comment: @melpomene I am sorry for the trouble. I am not competent in JS as you are sir.

Comment: @melpomene Keep in mind, the OP's issue may be a result of misunderstanding how module loading works, in which case, the require statements are very relevant to the code

Comment: @mhodges In that case an attempt at reducing the example may point out the issue and lead to a better/different question.

Comment: @melpomene It's possible - just something to keep in mind, that's all.

Comment: A bit clumsy but it can help : https://stackoverflow.com/a/44733777/1636522.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
this.config = _.merge(default_config, this.config);
```

is your problem. It assigns the same `default_config` object to all workers.

Comment: I really appreciate your help sir. I use `config` in the code. How can I set a config per worker which won't affect others?

Comment: I found out the error. It seems loadash `merge` recursively merges own and inherited enumerable string keyed properties of source objects into the destination object. Thanks for the help.