# When must I use the new keyword in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Sometimes I am supposed to call `new Foo()` to create a new foo object, but sometimes I can just call `Foo()` to create it.

In general, for a given function, how do I know which to use?

Comment: You should post the function's body, indeed, in my post, `john = Person("John")` yields `undefined`, thus, ignoring `new` does not always work.

Comment: To clarify @leaf, my question is: What should I look for in general, to know whether I should use `new` or not in a given situation? Today Foo, tomorrow Bar.

Comment: I'm afraid that this is mainly a matter of preference...

Answer (score 3):

#### What does the `new` keyword do?

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646698/what-is-the-new-keyword-in-javascript).

#### When should you use the `new` keyword?

- If the target function has a `.prototype.` and it doesn't return anything (or it returns `this`), then you should use `new` to get an object with that proto.  (Although some people [recommend using `Object.create(...)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3604157/99777) as a clearer alternative.)
- or, if the target function assigns things to `this.foo`, and you don't think it is trying to set things on the global object, then you should call it with `new`.

#### When should you NOT use the `new` keyword?

- If you are calling a factory function to create a new object, then you do not need to use the `new` keyword.

  A factory function will usually create the new object itself, and then return it.  It will create the object using `{ ... }` or `Object.create(...)` or by calling another function, or even by using `new` itself.

#### What will happen if you don't use the `new` keyword?

If you just call `Foo()` then the body of the Foo function will run with `this` pointing to the global object (or in strict mode, with `this === undefined`).  If the function assigns `this.foo` then these will end up modifying the global.  Is that what you wanted?

Answer (score 2):

Considering the following class :

```
Person = function (name) {
  this.name = name;
};
Person.prototype.getName = function () {
  return this.name;
};
```

Using `new` to instanciate this class :

```
john = new Person("John");
john.getName(); // "John"
```

Is roughly equivalent to the following :

```
john = {
  name: "John",
  __proto__: Person.prototype
};
john.getName(); // "John"
```

As you can see, `new` is nothing more than a syntactic sugar, it takes care of binding the prototype of the class to the instance, you don't have to do it yourself.

More about `new` : https://stackoverflow.com/a/44733777/1636522.