# Why is the prototype function not using the correct version of this?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, prototype, prototypal-inheritance

I am trying to understand the JS `prototype` inheritance mechanism which [es6](/questions/tagged/es6) uses. When I execute the below code in the browser([chrome](/questions/tagged/chrome) for example) the `ironman.villain();` function fails to read the `name` property from this.  I expect `this` to be the `MarvelHero` object, but it is actually a reference to the `window`.  `ironman.summarize()` also fails for a similar reason.  Why is this?

`ironman.introduce();` and `ironman.friends();` correctly reads the `this.name` variable and prints it.

```
var heroes = [];

// Hero constructor
function Hero (name, universe) {
  this.name = name;
  this.universe = universe;
  this.introduce = () => {
    return `I am ${this.name} and I belong to the ${this.universe} universe.`;
  }
  heroes.push(this);
}

// MarvelHero constructor
function MarvelHero (name) {
  this.universe = 'Marvel Comics';
  Hero.call(this, name, this.universe);
  this.friends = () => {
    return `${this.name} has friends: ${heroes.filter(hero => hero instanceof MarvelHero && hero.name !== this.name).map(hero => hero.name).join(', ')}.`;
  };
}

// DCHero constructor
function DCHero (name) {
  this.universe = 'DC Comics';
  Hero.call(this, name, this.universe);
  this.friends = () => {
    return `${this.name} has friends: ${heroes.filter(hero => hero instanceof DCHero && hero.name !== this.name).map(hero => hero.name).join(', ')}.`;
  };
}

// Parent prototype
Hero.prototype.summarize = () => {
  return `${this.name} => ${this.universe}`;
}

// Inherit from Hero's prototype
MarvelHero.prototype = Object.create(Hero.prototype);
DCHero.prototype = Object.create(Hero.prototype);

// Assign constructor prototypes to self
MarvelHero.prototype.constructor = MarvelHero;
DCHero.prototype.constructor = DCHero;

// MarvelHero prototype
MarvelHero.prototype.villain = () => {
  return `${this.name} has Loki`;
}

// DCHero prototype
DCHero.prototype.villain = () => {
  return `${this.name} has The Joker`;
}

let ironman = new MarvelHero('Ironman');
let captain = new MarvelHero('Captain America');
let spiderman = new MarvelHero('Spiderman');
let hulk = new MarvelHero('The Hulk');
let thor = new MarvelHero('Thor');
let doctor = new MarvelHero('Doctor Strange');
let panther = new MarvelHero('Black Panther');

let batman = new DCHero('Batman');
let superman = new DCHero('Superman');
let wonder = new DCHero('Wonder Woman');
let aquaman = new DCHero('Aquaman');

ironman.introduce();
ironman.friends();
ironman.villain();
ironman.summarize();

batman.introduce();
batman.friends();
batman.villain();
batman.summarize();
```

Comment: This problem has nothing to do with the `prototype` property.

Comment: A post you might find interesting : https://stackoverflow.com/a/48595448/1636522 :-)

Comment: An arrow function's *this* is set to the *this* of its outer execution context. In this case, the outer execution context is the global context where *this* is to the global/window object. Change `Hero.prototype.summarize = () => {...}` to `Hero.prototype.summarize = function () {...}`

Comment: Focus on the lookup mechanism, all the magic is there. One more post about `prototype` and its hidden brother `__proto__` : https://stackoverflow.com/a/41416177/1636522 :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your functions are defined on the global scope, and therefore this refer to the window object.

In order for this to refer to a parent, you need them to be part of an object

```
{
     DChero : function(name){}
}
```

Or wrap your code in parentheses and use it as an iife